# Image not showing on selected option

Tags: html, angular, material-design, html-select

There is an image in the select options along with text. But when I select any option, the image is not getting shown in the selected content.

```
 <mat-select>
   <mat-option [value]="1"><img src="assets/image/survey/short-text.png">Short Answer</mat-option>
   <mat-option [value]="2"><img src="assets/image/survey/paragraph.png">Paragraph</mat-tion>
   <mat-option [value]="3"><img src="assets/image/survey/redio.png" >Multiple Choice </mat-option>  
   <mat-option [value]="4"> <img src="assets/image/survey/chechbox.png">Checkbox</mat-option> 
   <mat-option [value]="5"><img src="assets/image/survey/date.png" >Date</mat-option>
   <mat-option [value]="6"><img src="assets/image/survey/linear-scale.png" >Linear cale</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

Comment: can you explain what is your issue, just show the that code does not explain anything

Comment: The problem is obviously your path. 'assets/image/survey/' is a relative path. Does your app know which suffix to attach in order to reach the absolute path? e.g. '/Users/user/angular/myApp/assets/image/survey/linear-scale.png'

Comment: I want to show the selected content as image + text, in drop down option it show image and text both  but after selecting option its showing only text

Comment: Are you using angular cli? If yes, and the images are in the correct `assets/image/survey` folder, don't forget to restart the cli after you've added these assets

Comment: can you try data-icon attribute of the option
`data-icon="assets/image/survey/paragraph.png"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi in span it is not possible to add  tag inside, so your should use background image of selected  like

```css
.selectedImg {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline;
}

.option1 {
    background: url("assets/image/survey/short-text.png") center / contain no-repeat;
}

.option2 {
    background: url("assets/image/survey/paragraph.png") center / contain no-repeat;
}

.option3 {
    background: url("assets/image/survey/redio.png") center / contain no-repeat;
}

.option4 {
    background: url("assets/image/survey/chechbox.png") center / contain no-repeat;
}

.option5 {
    background: url("assets/image/survey/date.png") center / contain no-repeat;
}

.option6 {
    background: url("assets/image/survey/linear-scale.png") center / contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<mat-select class="selectedImg" [(value)]="selected" [ngClass]="selected">
        <mat-option value="option1">
           <img src="assets/image/survey/short-text.png">Short Answer
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option2">
           <img src="assets/image/survey/paragraph.png">Paragraph
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option3">
           <img src="assets/image/survey/redio.png">Multiple Choice 
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option4">
           <img src="assets/image/survey/chechbox.png">Checkbox
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option5">
           <img src="assets/image/survey/date.png">Date
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option6">
           <img src="assets/image/survey/linear-scale.png">Linear cale
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```